# /usr/bin/env: 'ts-node-script\r': No such file or directory

Tags: node.js, typescript, ts-node

I'm trying to run a typescript file but the following error appears:

```
/usr/bin/env: 'ts-node-script\r': No such file or directory
```

I have ts-node installed in v10.4.0.

I have node installed in version v17.3.1